# Installing Truffle without npm

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, npm

I'm a student trying to install a truffle test RPC client (just for simple contract deployment in small scale).

I am using a remote Ubuntu machine in my university, and i don't root privileges.
Although npm is installed in the environment, i can't use it without sudo.

I already installed go-ethereum and geth using "git clone" and manual building (makefile building). I did not manage to do the same with the truffles repo.

Does any one know how to install truffle manually without npm?

Thanks

Comment: you can download and use the ganache which has a good UI for the contract, events logs, transactions and blocks. please check the link: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases

Comment: You can use [`npmrc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) file to configure where npm will install, for example inside your home user. Another alternative is to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and manager your own installation of node.